# Mailchimp Javascript request

Tags: javascript, curl, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have curl example request from mailchimp documentation, but I am new and can't convert this to javascript function

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/57afe96172/members' \
--user 'anystring:apikey' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"email_address":"urist.mcvankab+3@freddiesjokes.com", "status":"subscribed"}' \
--include
```

anyone can help me?

I have also this and works from browser url

```
https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxx&id=xxxxxxxx&email[email]=xxxxxxx&send_welcome=true
```

or how to convert this one?

Comment: use the browser url (its the same, but already decoded), search for `AJAX javascript` on google and use a javascript framework to save you some work with the AJAX call, like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines might work:

```
const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    try {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState !== 4) return;
        if (xmlHttp.status !== 200)
            throw new Error(
                xmlHttp.statusText || 'HTTP STATUS ' + xmlHttp.status
            );
        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
xmlHttp.open('POST', 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/57afe96172/members');
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('anystring' + ':' + 'apikey'));
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
xmlHttp.send('{"email_address":"urist.mcvankab+3@freddiesjokes.com", "status":"subscribed"}');
```